# How to mathematically generate percentage of a fixed value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issuing just knowing how to code the following requirement:

I have a list of teams and each team has 20 players. The names of each team is made up as the team name being the ‘FirstName’ and ‘Player…’ being the ‘Surname’ where an increment number (From ‘NumberID’) occurs after the string ‘Player’.

What I want to do is say for the 20 players per team, there must be the following positions entered under ‘Position’ field:

- GK (only for 2 players (other words 10% of players)
- DF (only for  6 players (other words 30% of players)
- MF (only for 6 players (other words 30% of players)
- FW (only for 6 players (other words 30% of players)

Then based on their positions, perform a random ‘PlayerWeighting’ for each player based on their ‘Position’ between 1 - 100

- GK – First 3% of Player Weighting (0 -3)
- DF – 4% - 30% of Player Weighting (4 - 30)
- MF – 31% - 60% of Player Weighting (31 - 60)
- FW – 61% - 99% of Player Weighting (61 - 99)
  Can I have help on coding this please?
  Below is what I have at the moment and the output it generates:

  ```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Player_CreateWholeTeam]
      @TeamID INT

  AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  BEGIN



      INSERT INTO dbo.Player (FirstName, Surname, TeamID)
      SELECT TeamName AS FirstName, 'Player' + cast(NumberID AS VARCHAR (10)) AS Surname, @TeamID
          FROM dbo.Team t
          CROSS JOIN dbo.Number n
          WHERE TeamID = @TeamID
          AND n.NumberID <= 20

  -- abs(checksum(newid()) % 99) + 1 AS PlayerWeighting,

  select * from dbo.Player

  END
  ```

  OUTPUT ('Player' table):

[image]

Comment: Are you simply assigning a random value (from 1 to 100) to each player to arrive at the weighting? then assessing that by position? what happens if a player has several positions?

Comment: Yeah just a random value, no player will have multiple positions. It's fixed postions

Comment: You have GK/DF/DF/DF in your weighting table description. That's probably wrong?

Comment: @TToni Yeah sorry about that, should be GF/DF/MF/FW, good spot

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using? And does the weighting value need to be unique?

Comment: @TToni SQL Server 2012 and it doesn't have to be unique

Comment: Would it be OK if the first two players always get GK, the next six always get DF and so on?

Comment: Prefer random but if you can't do it random, then do it a fixed position for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [Searched CASE expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.110).aspx) for the remaining two columns in your `SELECT`:

```
CASE
  WHEN n.NumberId BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 'GK'
  WHEN n.NumberId BETWEEN 3 AND 8 THEN 'DF'
  ...
END AS Position,
CASE
  WHEN n.NumberId BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 4
  WHEN n.NumberId BETWEEN 3 AND 8 THEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 27 + 4
  ...
END AS PlayerWeigthing,
```

If you also want to randomize the player numbers, you have to create a random mapping for your numbers, like this:

```
DECLARE @RNumber AS TABLE(n int IDENTITY(1,1), rn INT)

INSERT @RNumber 
  SELECT NumberID as rn FROM dbo.Number
    WHERE NumberID <= 20
    ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Then you can join with that instead of your original number table and use `n` and `rn` as needed.